# Table based menu won't respond to @media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive menu with the CSS table value that puts each li item on a seperate line at 100% width when the browser is reduced in size. No matter how I do it and on which element I apply the value, it will not work. I have tried putting the table, table-row, and table-cell on different elements, but no joy. I have put a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wccukpjm/) which shows the menu. However, if the browser is resized to make it smaller you will see that the menu responds to the @media query only by making the row 100% width with the list items apparently taking up 20% each.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){

.nav
{
    display : table ;
    border-collapse : collapse ;
    width : 100% ;
    position : relative ;
    top : 40px 
}

ul.menu 
{
    list-style : none ;
    padding : 0 ;
    margin : 0 ;
    display : table-row ;
    width : 100%
}

ul.menu li > li
{
    width : 100% ;
    display : table-cell ;
}

}
```

However, if I apply the same code without the media query it does what I want it to do. You can see this at the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/crnvsvbv/) which allows the li items to be 100% width. I have spent hours on this trying different things including past answers on stackoverflow.

Oh, lastly I have tried formatting the li items in the html with or without whitespace I originally typed the html for inline-block menu display. How I type the li items in the HTML also makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how a table works...

Table cells are aligned next to each other along each table row.

You need to change the display property to block on the li's for them to drop below one another.

```css
body
{
    margin : 0 ;
    padding : 0 ;
    font : sans-serif ;
    height : 100% 
}

.header
{
    background-color : #006400 ;
    width : 100% ;
    padding : 0 ;
    height : 160px ;
    line-height : 160px ;
    color : white ;
    text-align : center ;
    margin-bottom : 0 ;
}

.header h1 
{
    padding : 0 ;
    margin : 0
}

.menuplace
{
    background-color : #328332 ;
    width : 100% ;
    height : 90px ;
    margin-top : 0 ;
    color : white 
}

.nav
{
    display : table ;
    position : relative ;
    border-collapse : collapse ;
    top : 40px ;
    margin : 0 auto
}

.menu 
{
    list-style : none ;
    padding : 0 ;
    margin : 0 ;
    display : table-row ;
}

.menu li 
{
    display : table-cell
}

.menu li a
{
    text-decoration : none ;
    padding : 15px ;
    display : block ;
    background-color : #006400 ;
    color : white ;
    margin : 0 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px){

.nav
{
    display : block ;
    width : 100% ;
    position : relative ;
    top : 40px 
}

ul.menu 
{
    list-style : none ;
    padding : 0 ;
    margin : 0 ;
    display : block ;
    width : 100%
}

ul.menu li
{
    width : 100% ;
    display : block ;
}

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header">

<h1>Proper Sound website</h1>

</div>

<div class="menuplace">

<div class="nav">

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Home</a></li><li>
<a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>
</li><li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</li><li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</li><li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>




</body>
```

Comment: Pure genius Aaron. I was going over the basics in my head but thought that 100% on the li items would make them wrap. Many thanks.